# Directory of museum collections online

Tags: database

What is the most comprehensive directory of museum online collections as of today? It seems there was an ICOM page for that but apparently it's no longer available.

Comment: Did you already try searching for [museum+collection+metadata](https://www.google.nl/search?q=museum+collection+metadata)?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Names of pieces? Images? Descriptions?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for names, creators, creation dates, technique, material, provenance, size, digital image, inventory number, bibliography, descriptions but sometimes even a thumbnail image with title only is useful ;) Strangely, in spite of the fact that hundreds or thousands of museums publish their collections online there is no a simple up-to-date list of urls of online collections arranged geographically or in any other way.

Comment: @JanDoggen this query looks promising but does not return any interesting results. Maybe except this list http://collections.si.edu/search/about.htm#museum-collections which is exactly what I'm looking for, except it's very short.